# how to trim the absolute directory path?

Tags: regex, unix, pcre, pcregrep

I have a absolute path to directory halo:
**/pkg/check/power/halo**

I want to trim the absolute path to only:
**/pkg/halo**

how can i do that using regex or pcreCompile function or unix?

Comment: Why is this tagged _bash_?

Comment: you can remove it

Comment: @SurabhS Switching from bash to tcl to perl to C, what are you looking for?? What's the context? Also, your _"I want to trim"_ is not clear; do you want to keep the `first` and `last` components or the ones that match `pkg` and `halo`?

Answer (score 3):

When working with paths, you're *strongly* recommended to use `file split` and `file join` as they handle weirdnesses you're not aware of.

```
set path /pkg/check/power/halo
set pieces [file split $path]
set result [file join {*}[lrange $pieces 0 1] [lindex $pieces end]]
```

Or (removing pieces rather than selecting them):

```
set result [file join {*}[lreplace $pieces 2 end-1]]
```

Comment: That should be the way to go

Answer (score 2):

With tcl:

```
set path "/pkg/check/power/halo"
set path [ split $path / ]
set path /[lindex $path 1]/[lindex $path end]
```

Comment: Maybe use `file split` and `file join` to better handle any odd stuff that might come up with real paths?

Comment: can you have any expamle @Shawn

Comment: @SurabhS `set parts [file split $path]; puts [file join {*}[lreplace $parts 2 end-1]]`